# Set up a custom domain on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, subdomain

I have tried googling around but not quite found a solution to my problem. I have a domain already http://name.example.com. I have an app hosted on heroku http://app.herokuapp.com. I want to set up using WHM/CPANEL. I have already added the subdomain on heroku as described on their docs

```
heroku domains:add www.name.example.com
```

Running `heroku domains` outputs both url

```
=== myapp Domain Names
myapp.herokuapp.com
www.name.example.com
```

Heroku says from then on `configure your DNS with a CNAME record pointing the subdomain to your app’s Heroku herokuapp.com hostname`. I actually don't know how to proceed from here from the whm/cpanel. Anyone with previous experience on how to do this?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

What provider you are using for you domain? It's very easy.

You need to login into your domain provider site and create a a DNS record.

If you are using some good domain provider you can get some screen shot helps online.